# Why doesn't the following CRTP hierarchy compile?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, hierarchy, friend, crtp

I am trying to implement a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) hierarchy of classes. I am interested in the base class to have access to the data member of a derived class down the chain:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Derived>
class A {
public:
    void showv() {
        std::cout << static_cast<const Derived*>(this)->v << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class Derived>
class B : public A< Derived > {
    typedef A<Derived> base;
    friend base;
};

class fromA : public A<fromA> {
    typedef A<fromA> base;
    friend base;
protected:
    int v = 1;
};

class fromB : public B<fromB>
{
    typedef B<fromB> base;
    friend base;
protected:
    int v = 2;
};

int main()
{
    // This runs ok
    fromA derived_from_a;
    derived_from_a.showv();

    // Why doesn't the following compile and complains about the protected member?
    fromB derived_from_b;
    derived_from_b.showv();

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j7Mgq1Qtge7ppATf)

Although the first derived class (`fromA`) compiles and runs as expected, the second (`fromB`), that derives from a class derived from`A`, doesn't.

1. What is the reason the friend declarations are not channeled through?
2. Any suggestions on a workaround?

Comment: why not to create virtual function getV() and override it in each derived class instead of games with friends?

Comment: `friend` of my `friend` are not my friend in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is: the friend of my friend is not my friend.

In `fromA` you have

```
typedef A<fromA> base;
friend base;
```

Which makes `A<fromA>` a friend and `show` can access `fromA`'s protected member.

In `fromB` you also have

```
typedef B<fromB> base;
friend base;
```

But this doesn't make `A` a friend, it makes `B` your friend.  Even though A is a friend of `B` it does not mean it is also now a friend of `fromB` and this is why you cannot access `v` in `show`.

One way you can fix this is to make `typedef A<Derived> base;` public or protected in `B` and then in `fromB` you can add `friend base::base;` which would give `A` access.

Comment: It works, thanks! For some reason, I thought `base` was chaining its result all the way up to `fromB`.